# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement (with SUM)

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE #tmpDocAcq
SET #tmpDocAcq.PVOptionals = SUM(wtDocAchL.PAHT)
FROM #tmpDocAcq
INNER JOIN wtDocAchL ON #tmpDocAcq.idDocAch = wtDocAchL.idDocAch
WHERE wtDocAchL.idNatCost = '2'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Microsoft SQL Server; try:

```
WITH cte As
(
    SELECT
        idDocAch,
        SUM(PAHT) As PAHT
    FROM
        wtDocAchL
    WHERE
        idNatCost = '2'
    GROUP BY
        idDocAch
)
UPDATE T
SET PVOptionals = D.PAHT
FROM #tmpDocAcq As T
INNER JOIN cte As D ON D.idDocAch = T.idDocAch;
```